# Problems with choice prompt

Tags: c#, botframework

Not sure how to use choiceprompt

```
    private async Task<DialogTurnResult> PromptForRequestStepAsync(WaterfallStepContext stepContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
            return await stepContext.PromptAsync(
    RequestPrompt,
    new PromptOptions
    {
        Prompt = MessageFactory.Text("Please choose a location."),
        RetryPrompt = MessageFactory.Text("Sorry, please choose a location from the list."),
        Choices = ChoiceFactory.ToChoices(new List<string> { "1", "2", "3" }),
    });
        }

    private async Task<DialogTurnResult> PromptForTutorialStepAsync(WaterfallStepContext stepContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        // Save name, if prompted.
        var context = stepContext.Context;
        var location = stepContext.Result;
        var greetingState = await UserProfileAccessor.GetAsync(context);
        greetingState.Request = stepContext.Result as string;

        await UserProfileAccessor.SetAsync(stepContext.Context, greetingState);

        if (greetingState.Request == "1")
        {
            var opts = new PromptOptions
            {
                Prompt = new Activity
                {
                    Type = ActivityTypes.Message,
                    Text = $"1- Login to OneDrive" + Environment.NewLine + "2- Upload a file" + Environment.NewLine + "3- Create a folder",
                },
            };
            return await stepContext.PromptAsync(OneDrivePrompt, opts);
        }
```

When I run the bot. The options show up and I can press the button with "1" to input 1. I am not sure how to make the next step of the waterfallstep work with the choiceprompt I used. The code worked when i was doing a simple textprompt. I changed it to choiceprompt and it does not work. What do I need to do to make it work?

Comment: Did my answer below help? If so it would be great if you could upvote and/or mark it as the answer so it helps other people in the future.

Comment: Sorry I amq uite new to this and I do not have the repututation for that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you're saying that the prompt with the id value in your `RequestPrompt` variable is defined as a `ChoicePrompt`?

If so a `ChoicePrompt`'s result will be a `FoundChoice` instance. So, assuming the step that follows that prompt is the `PromptForTutorialStepAsync` you show here, you would cast the result to a `FoundChoice` and then use that API to access the actual value.

The simplest, though arguable not the most legible, way would be as follows:

```
var location = ((FoundChoice)stepContext.Result).Value;
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a repository to look at to see the difference between working and broken?

From the current glance, here are a couple of things to check:
1) The "return await stepContext.PromptAsync(OneDrivePrompt, opts);" looks like an unnecessary await. Let the Task class do it's work.

2) Do you know at which line the program stops?

Comment: the program allows me to choose an option, but after I chose the option it was unable to save the answer and the program goes to an else statement where an answer is not given.

Comment: FWIW, the await is correct here; it's causing the DialogTurnResult that's return asynchronously from the call to PromptAsync as the result of his step.